# Generate an organisational chart from Office 365

Tags: powershell, visio

We are, like many companies, using Office 365 for collaborative work.

O365 is aware of direct reports, and has access to many type of data regarding employee and the company structure.

Is there a way using Microsoft Flow, Visio or Powershell to generate a dynamic organisation chart, or CSV containing user records and direct reports ?

I explored `Get-MsolUser` but couldn't work out how to get the "Direct Report" or "Manager" field.

Comment: Short answer: yes.  What have you tried so far code-wise?

Comment: Read the information from O365, then use Visio's [Organization Chart](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-an-organization-chart-automatically-from-employee-data-8f2e693e-25fc-410e-8264-9084eb0b9360) feature to build it.